# Preserve the "active" color of a tab on "focusOut"

Tags: jquery

I have a a jQuery tabs UI, that changes color when active or focused

CSS:

```
            a {
                color: grey;
                &:focus {
                    color: green;
                }
                &:hover {
                    color: green !important;
                }
                &:active {
                    color: green !important;
                }
            }
```

When I `focusout` it reverts back to the default color. I am trying to think of a jQuery solution for this, which also gets rid of the `active` color of the last tab clicked if a new one is selected.

JS:

```
        if($("#first-tab, #second-tab, #third-tab").focusout {
            $(this).addClass('green');
        }else{
            $('#first-tab, #second-tab, #third-tab').removeClass('green');
        }
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

you can add an class which says its clicked and you can add your style to that class

```
$("a").on("click",function(){ 
   $("a").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
});

a.active{color:green}
```

Comment: This is not solving the problem of preserving the color when focusing out.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `:visited` selector.

```
a:visited { 
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Does it fade away when I focus out of the anchor tag? It's not working for some reason. PLus, this would keep the rest of the tabs green when they're actually not active.

Comment: @nosille Can you please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demonstrating what you currently have so I can help you better?

Comment: @nosille You would need to remove the `green` class or it will override this CSS.